# Windows 11's new media player cannot play opus encoded audio in mp4 file

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11, windows-media-player, codec

`youtube-dl-gui` allows choosing to download a video as an `.mp4` file or an `.mkv` file. According to VLC, both options end up having the audio portion encoded as Opus audio. However, attempting to play the `.mp4` version with Windows 11's new media player results in it complaining:

> We can't play the audio for filename.mp4. It's encoded in Opus format which isn't supported. You can still watch the video.

Playing the `.mkv` version with the new Windows 11 media player works perfectly fine, though, despite both versions having Opus audio (according to VLC, at least).

Is there anything I can do to get it to play back the `.mp4` version as well?

Comment: You perhaps need a codec pack. I recommend the [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, that fixed it for the old Windows Media Player, however the new Windows 11 one still complains.

Comment: But if you're deliberately downloading the video as .mp4, wouldn't you also want to download AAC audio rather than Opus?

Comment: If one media plater found the codec and the new one didn't, then it's just broken. I haven't used the Windows media player since I discovered [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/). Recommended.

Comment: @user1686 It doesn't let me choose it seems, the only options are video+audio or audio only, and in the case of video + audio, it only lets me choose the video format, not the audio in it. I don't know how `youtube-dl` works, but I assume that's just how it found the video from youtube itself.

Comment: @harrymc Well that is an option I suppose, though I find having consistent looks pleasing. While functional, VLC certainly doesn't look as "belonging" as the new Windows 11 media player. Regardless, still hoping to get that new player to work.

Comment: @404NameNotFound: All YouTube videos have both formats available (they have to, as Safari on macOS/iOS only supports H.264+AAC) – it sounds like a problem with the GUI app if it doesn't let you select that. Does it let you input custom --format options? `"bestvideo[vcodec^=avc1]+bestaudio[acodec^=mp4a]"` should do it.

Comment: Have you configured Media Player to download codecs automatically in menu *Tools > Options > Player tab*, select "Download codecs automatically" and OK?

Comment: @user1686 Alas, it doesn't seem to let me input custom flags. At least I now know how I can download with the format I want, thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't answer the question on how to get the new Windows 11 media player to understand Opus audio.

Comment: @harrymc Which media player are you referring to, the old Windows Media Player or the new Windows 11 one?  Either way, I'm unable to find the settings you describe.

Comment: The option has disappeared. Maybe it's now in Player tab "Connect to the internet", and/or in Library tab "Retrieve additional information from the Internet". Or elsewhere.

Comment: @harrymc If I'm understanding correctly, you're referring to [these settings](https://imgur.com/a/EJJiyyy) from the old Windows Media Player - that one managed to play back the `.mp4` video with the audio after installing the codec pack you recommended. I'm looking for a solution for the new Windows 11 one, that one still complains after installing the codec pack.

Comment: Yes, these settings and anything that mentions internet. The new player might be unable to use this codec for some unknown reason. The only direction I could think of was to make it download a codec that it can use (if one exists). Otherwise, you could signal the bug in the Feedback Hub and don't use the new player for this kind of media.

Comment: @harrymc I see, thanks for the assistance thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `Web Media Extensions` from Microsoft Store. This is required by UWP apps to play Opus files, and Media Player seems to be an UWP app.

If this is not enough, it might be due to an issue with UAC. Try enabling "User Account Control" on Windows Settings by choosing at least the "(default)" setting. Or you can enable it manually by changing this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA
```

And set the value to `1`